# Add product in cart according website by GraphQl

Tags: magento2, graphql

How can we add products in the cart according to the website?

I have multiple websites in a single Magento installation. When I am adding a product by GraphQl then it's adding the product on the base website. Not in the targeted website.

Even my all website URL is different and Graphql endpoint also using according to the website. But it's adding  in base website

For example, My endpoint is below

**[www.example-website2.com/graphql](http://www.example-website2.com/graphql)**

But it's adding the product in below website

**[www.example-website1.com/graphql](http://www.example-website1.com/graphql)**

Where I need to pass website id in below mutation. I have created token and cart id from this URL **[www.example-website2.com/graphql](http://www.example-website2.com/graphql)**

```
mutation {
  addSimpleProductsToCart(
    input: {
      cart_id: "{ CART_ID }"
      cart_items: [
        {
          data: {
            quantity: 1
            sku: "simple-product"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ) {
    cart {
      items {
        id
        product {
          sku
          stock_status
        }
        quantity
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official documentation says Magento accepts the following headers in a GraphQL request:
Store code is one among them, so you can pass store code as a header parameter.

- Authorization
- Content-Currency
- Content-Type
- Preview-Version
- Store

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/graphql/send-request.html

Never tested though, but this will guide you.